# Getting weird completions in shell mode

Tags: completion, shell-mode

I'm getting unexpected completion suggestions in shell mode using company. For instance:
[image]

I have no idea why it's suggesting random DLL filenames here. This is in Linux Emacs built from master of 2022-01-18, on Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL (Windows 11).

I pared my .emacs down to this (I omitted the usual straight.el setup code):

```
(use-package company
  :bind (("M-RET" . company-complete))
  :demand
  :config (global-company-mode)
  (setq company-backends '(company-capf))
)
```

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this. The problem is not in company; I think it's that completion-at-point-function is returning these DLL names rather than anything useful (such as "then", in this case).
Where should I look to start debugging this?

Comment: These seem like semi-legitimate completions to me. At this point, any name of an executable file in a directory on the command search path is a valid completion. Presumably those `.dll` files are in a directory on the command search path. However, `.dll` files should probably not be considered executable — on Windows, there should be a filter by extension.

Comment: That's fair, I guess. And I do think these are coming from comint completion (as you imply). But I'd expect "then" to be on the list as well, from shell-mode.

Comment: @GaryO `sh-completion-at-point-function` lives inside core Emacs, so your best bet to see it improve would be `M-x report-emacs-bug`.